# Should the request for blade graphic question be changed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, specific-question

This question got a close vote from be as it is asking for external resources it not useful to all users and we want people to stay here.

[Is there a collection of good reference signage for saw blade types?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/3365/what-are-some-good-shop-graphics-for-saws-in-a-community-workspaces)

This question now has a bounty on it as well which I don't know if that changes the game or not.

Is this question on topic? What should we do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this question has been sitting for a while.

"Good reference graphics" is categorically opinion-based. The infinite selection of possible graphics also makes it tend to "too broad". The question should have been closed by now, and I have voted to close it accordingly.

The quality of answers on it is still expectedly low even after a bounty and a few weeks. If I had the privileges I would vote to delete it as well, as I don't feel the site should publicly archive low quality information, and I do not see that question as having the potential to garner high quality information in the future.

Comment: I didn't realize, until reading another SO meta post, that bounties could be removed from questions. That is what I am going to push for next time this happens. There is a good question in there but we need to remove the fluff.

Answer (score 1):

I think a rewording of this would make the question on-topic, useful to all including the op. An excerpt from the question at this time:

> People in my community wood shop don't always remember the difference between types of saw blades for the table saw and band saw.

While having a visual aid for this is important the root of the question is really

> How can I recognize the different blade types

I think that we can reword this question into at least one question where it is just asking about the different table saw / circular saw blades types. (two different blade types might require two questions)

Once the OP is aware of the different types he could, on his own, create his own visual guide with all the information that he would have learned from the answers.

Comment: I thought about working on this question and immediately found that I could not find any charts that both showed a broad array of blade types and what they are applicable for.  I can understand why he might ask for help finding a good one. It might be just as good to ask another question

Comment: I think you can try.  I've been struggling with that one since it came up.

Comment: @bowlturner I want to for sure. But at this point I am going to wait until the OP of the question chimes in. Seems fair I think.

Comment: @ ashlar, and all. I have had a very hard time finding these types of graphical references.  Making my own signage may be a worthwhile thing for my time, but as I have a task list a mile long for improving the makerspace, and i'm not particularly confident in my ability to do so from a knowledge standpoint as well as a graphical design standpoint. i'd hoped for someone else's professional grade visual that i can just print.

Comment: I also considered asking the same question for each type of saw to perhaps make the question(s) narrower - but wasn't sure if that was compounding the problem if the nature of the question is a bad fit to begin with. also, since there haven't been any takers, it may just not exist, and then would remain an unanswered question which is perhaps not good.